# Inconsistent behavior of Julia ccall

Tags: c, windows, julia

I'm attempting to use ccall to interface with a Windows function (FindWindowA to be specific), but i'm getting a weird behavior

```
julia> ccall((:FindWindowA, :user32), Int32, (Ptr{Cvoid},), C_NULL)
855386

julia> foo() = ccall((:FindWindowA, :user32), Int32, (Ptr{Cvoid},), C_NULL)
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
0

julia> @ccall :user32.FindWindowA(C_NULL::Ptr{Cvoid})::Int32
65920

julia> foo() = @ccall :user32.FindWindowA(C_NULL::Ptr{Cvoid})::Int32
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
0
```

Is there a way to get consistent results from ccall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try providing second parameter to the function as well, according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa):

```
julia> @ccall :user32.FindWindowA(C_NULL::Ptr{Cvoid})::Int32
65896

julia> boo() = @ccall :user32.FindWindowA(C_NULL::Ptr{Cvoid}, C_NULL::Ptr{Cvoid})::Int32
boo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> boo()
65896
```